# How to read GML file with OGR library (GDAL\OGR)?

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to read GML file (version 3.2.1) using OGR 1.6 in python 2.6.

I am getting following error:

```
*ERROR 1: Unable to create Xerces C++ based GML reader, Xerces support
not configured into GDAL/OGR.
ERROR 1: File D:\cp.gml appears to be GML but the GML reader can't
be instantiated, likely because Xerces support wasn't
configured in.*
```

My question is:

Am I missing some libraries? 
Is it possible to work with GML files with my versions of GDAL\OGR and python?

Comment: You do not say enough details. Do other conversions (or Python GDAL/OGR opearions) ever work ? How did you install it ? Did you follow the advices of [GdalOgrInPython – GDAL](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython) form GDAL/OGR wiki ?

Comment: I'd recommend upgrading to a newer release of GDAL. If your on Windows, [try this build](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal), which may also require you also update Numpy from the same website.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to a newer version of GDAL/OGR (1.11) as suggested by Mike T helped. Unfortunately I dont know why.